# Purpose: Want to Validate user-Input Schema and check the real-time data in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, schema, real-time

My case states that a User input some data as a Schema ,and that schema is Used for Validation and according to that data is allowed to store in the database.I am using mongoDB as a database. I don't know how to go forth for the Validation of this kind,i.e that can be changed as user wants. I am aware of mongoDB schema Validation but this allow to predefine the Validators as I will create a schema but this will not help. Any Idea How can I achieve this! I have made a data acquisition part in node.js using mongoDB-npm that saves the oncoming mqtt messages into the database.

Answer (score 0):

ajv should do do what you want.

See https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv

Comment: Thank you @L.Sanna .I have used josnSchema's validator -npm , but when I pass my saved Schema from the database it's not working. I have to explicitly define schema object then it works OK . Should I change Over to ajv. Which should be better in this case i.e, when I get schema from my db and use it to validate another collection.